# Angular2-JWT package no longer working in Angular 6 (RXJS import issues)

Tags: angular, rxjs, jwt, angular6

So I have this package called Angular2-jwt that I use to define whether a user is logged in. Today I transfered an existing app to another app that works on Angular 6. The package is now throwing the following errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\projects\Harry-Potter-WU\node_modules\angular2-jwt'
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/observable/defer' in
'C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\projects\Harry-Potter-WU\node_modules\angular2-jwt'
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise' in 'C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\projects\Harry-Potter-WU\node_modules\angular2-jwt'
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap' in 'C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\projects\Harry-Potter-WU\node_modules\angular2-jwt'
```

I had other rxjs issues because of Angular 6, but with these ones I can't find info on how to solve them. Anyone an idea? the package code below (I highlighted the troubled areas):

[image]

Comment: https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rxjs 6 Changed its internal structure so you change your imports

For the import statements, here's how you have to update your code:

Observable, Subject etc.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

becomes

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

For More:https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: So in my particular case the changes should be "require('rxjs')" and "require('rxjs/operators')" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please import compatible backward version:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/compat